# SQL query from 2 tables with count

Tags: sql, count, group-by

I have 2 tables, table `A` and table `B`.

Table `A` has these fields:

```
id(primary key), 
references_id
```

Table `B` also has fields:

```
id(primary_key) 
references_id.
```

Now I am given the ids of `A`, I need to retrieve `A.id` and the `count(B.references_id)` by `A.references_id`.

How can I do that in a SQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` so it will still show even if the `references_id` is not present on table `B`. Try something like this,

```
SELECT  a.ID, COUNT(b.References_ID) totalCount
FROM    A LEFT JOIN B
            ON a.References_ID = b.References_ID
GROUP BY a.ID
```

Comment: +1 for `left join` and `COUNT(b.References_ID)` to get counts of 0

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.Id, COUNT(B.references_id)
FROM A
INNER JOIN B A.Reference_ID = B.References_ID
GROUP BY A.Id
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to toss another option in there, this time with a correlated sub-query:

```
select a.id, (select count(*) from b where references_id = a.id) as ref_count
from a as a
```

Oddly enough, this can sometimes give a more efficient execution plan than the `join and group by` solution.  I often try both.